# Importing with dot notation

Tags: python, module, python-import

Can someone explain this to me?
When you import `Tkinter.Messagebox` what actually does this mean (Dot Notation)?
I know that you can import `Tkinter` but when you import `Tkinter.Messagebox` what actually is this? Is it a class inside a class?

I am new to Python and dot notation confuses me sometimes.

Comment: That's a class inside a module. That means only Messagebox class would be available for you, while import Tkinter would import all the classes. I recommend trying this in python IDLE and play around with it.

Comment: if you read the docs i hope you will find a good explanation rather than here on SO

Comment: @Vinny: It's not a class inside a module. It's a module inside a package.

Comment: Please check the casing, there is no `Tkinter.Messagebox` anywhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're putting that dot in your imports, you're referring to something inside the package/file you're importing from.
what you import can be a class, package or a file, each time you put a dot you ask something that is inside the instance before it.

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    file.py
    one/
        __init__.py
        anotherfile.py
    two/
        __init__.py
    three/
        __init__.py
```

for example you have this, when you pass `import parent.file` you're actually importing another python module that may contain classes and variables, so to refer to a specific variable or class inside that file you do `from parent.file import class` for example.

this may go further, import a packaging inside another package or a class inside a file inside a package etc (like `import parent.one.anotherfile`)
For more info read [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) about this.

Comment: `import parent.file.class` doesn't make sense: this form of the import statement imports only modules and packages. (Try `import decimal.Decimal`, for example. It doesn't work.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I edited it, works now? I tried not including `from .. import ..` since he's a beginner.

Comment: @GeekyMo I understand what you are telling me but when I import Tkinter I also get some functions to use.In your example if I import parent I will get nothing.
I mean parent is just a folder right?It has nothing in it.
So is Tkinter a package or  a module?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos if you import a package (a parent) you actually import its `__init__` file which represents that folder is a python package, so if you import Tkinter, it'll import` __init__` file inside the Tkinter package folder, which may or may not include functions, when you import something inside it like `from Tkinter import func`, it'll go search through` __init__` first, then goes and looks for modules in that package.

Comment: Tkinter, is a folder, which contains an `__init__.py` to tell python it's a package, and about its type, it depends, if you `import Tkinter`, you actually import `__init__` module inside it, if you do `from Tkinter import module` or `import Tkinter.module` (in some cases) you're treating Tkinter a package of python modules.

Answer (score 8):

`import a.b` imports `b` into the namespace `a`, you can access it by `a.b` .  Be aware that this only works if `b` is a module. (e.g. `import urllib.request` in Python 3)

`from a import b` however imports `b` into the current namespace, accessible by `b`. This works for classes, functions etc.

Be careful when using from - import:

```
from math import sqrt
from cmath import sqrt
```

Both statements import the function `sqrt` into the current namespace, however, the second import statement overrides the first one.

Comment: "`import a.b` imports `b` into the namespace `a`" This was helpful. I assumed that all "sub-modules" of `a` would automatically be imported when I import `a`, but that seems not to be the case in Python - you need to specifically import the sub-modules. But only sometimes? Something to do with it being a property/attribute vs a new module/file?